# TcpSockets android: How to return from bufferreader.readline without server response

Tags: android, sockets, tcpsocket

Below code is implemented in AsynTask and with try-catch. I want to interrupt bufferreader.readline() if server does not respond with in Specified time. How can I achieve this?

```
    Socket tcpSocket = new Socket();

    tcpSocket.connect(new InetSocketAddress("mydomain.com", 5000),
                SOCK_TIMEOUT);

    InputStream inputStream = tcpSocket.getInputStream();

    BufferedReader bufferReader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

    String jsonData = bufferReader.readLine(); //blocks here
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply close the socket and it will return with socket exception.